# Onclick/Ajax on the Generate OTP without reloading?

Tags: php, ajax, onclick

I am having an issue that **how to send the number to next page** where it handles the mobile number and send a message to the user mobile number. By Using onClick method or by using ajax method can we send the message without reloading the page like below in the code.

**index.php**

```
    <form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" maxlength="10">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="otp" placeholder="OTP" maxlength="11" style="width: 40%; float: left;">

                    <input type="submit" id="btnonOtp" value="Generate OTP" class="form-control" style="background-color:#005995;width: 56.5%; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 12px; border-radius: 0;">
   </form>

$('#btnonOtp').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: test.php,
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            text: mobile,
            value: mobile
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert('OTP Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

**Test.php**

```
    <?php 
include 'send.php'; 


$_SESSION['smsotp'] = sms_OTP();
$num=$_POST['mobile'];
$number = $num; 
//$text = 'Hi There, how are you?'; 
$sms_api_result = sms_Send($number, 'Please do not share the one time password with anyone. Your One Time password is: '.$_SESSION['smsotp'],$debug);

?>
```

If I run the test.php with mobile number passing directly then the message is delivered, but I need to pass the mobile number dynamically to $num variable.

Can any one help me where I am going wrong??

Comment: did you add form tag in your code?

Comment: try to echo $num what you getting ?

Comment: #Karan ya tried with form tag to put only for that mobile number and OTP part to send the value to next page. But still it doesn't work. And the page loads once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'data' object in your ajax isn't passing the right value.
First, add an id to the mobile  tag,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" maxlength="10">
```

Second, change the input type of the buttom from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. This is required because 'submit' by default does a full page submit, even if you have an click handler defined for it. [the click function also gets executed but after than the page submit happens as well.]

And then update your click function like the one below.

```
$('#btnonOtp').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: test.php,
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            // The key is 'mobile'. This will be the same key in $_POST[] that holds the mobile number value.
            mobile: $('#mobile').val()
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert('OTP Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

This should solve your core problem.

**Debugging hint**: To check if the data is being passed correctly, in test.php you can do a `var_dump($_POST)`. This will print all the key-value pairs that were received. This should help you to analyse what is usually missing.

P.S: Also, as a good practice you might want to add a validation on the Value of the mobile number field to ensure the data entered by the user indeed looks like a mobile number.

Comment: I have done according to the above code but still the value is not taking to next page.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of $_POST here please? Alternatively, you may also do a console.log(msg) inside the 'success' call back and paste it here.

Comment: Sorry in the ajax the URL it not enclosed with the double quotes. Now I thing the value is passing and I am getting the alert "OTP Sent". But how to capture in the test,php file. where i have included the $_POST['mobile'] in the page.

Comment: these are contents i am getting in console. array(1) {
  ["mobile"]=>
  string(10) "1234567890"
}
1234567890

Comment: your code works for me. Thanks. I have up voted the answer.

Comment: I don't see the upvote but glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code that can help you:

NOTE: Please check if mobile number is getting in $number variable or not.

```
 <?php 
include 'send.php'; 


$_SESSION['smsotp'] = sms_OTP();
$number = (int) $_POST['mobile']; 
//$text = 'Hi There, how are you?'; 
$sms_api_result = sms_Send($number, 'Please do not share the one time password with anyone. Your One Time password is: '.$_SESSION['smsotp'],$debug);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
M.AutoInit(),$(document).ready(function(){var e=$(window).height(),t=$(".row.main-background").height();$(document).height();t<e&&$(".row.main-background").css("height","100%"),$("body").css("height",e)});var Email=localStorage.getItem("Email"),Name=localStorage.getItem("Name"),Id=localStorage.getItem("Id"),Cognito_ID=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID");Email&&Name&&Id&&""!=Cognito_ID&&(window.location.href="matches.html");var selectedValue,referral,referralValue=[];function myFunction(){var e=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID");if(null!=(t=localStorage.getItem(e+".CrickingDuelsUserInfo")))var t=localStorage.getItem(e+".CrickingDuelsUserInfo");else $("#overlayLoader").hide(),$("#verification").modal("open",{onOpenStart:function(){$("main").addClass("filter-blur"),$("footer").addClass("filter-blur")},onCloseStart:function(){$("main").removeClass("filter-blur"),$("footer").removeClass("filter-blur")}}),document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepOne").style.display="block",document.getElementById("accountReferralCode").style.display="none";var n=JSON.parse(t);if(null==n&&(client=new AWS.CognitoSyncManager,client.openOrCreateDataset("CrickingDuelsUserInfo",function(e,t){SyncData(t)})),null!=t){null==n.ReferralTaken&&($("#overlayLoader").hide(),$("#verification").modal("open",{onOpenStart:function(){$("main").addClass("filter-blur"),$("footer").addClass("filter-blur")},onCloseStart:function(){$("main").removeClass("filter-blur"),$("footer").removeClass("filter-blur")}}),document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepOne").style.display="block",document.getElementById("accountReferralCode").style.display="none");var o=n.ReferralTaken.Key,a=n.ReferralTaken.Value;if(null!=n.SelectedState){var c=n.SelectedState.Key;n.SelectedState.Value;"SelectedState"==c&&localStorage.setItem("user_state","restricted")}"ReferralTaken"==o&&"true"==a&&($("#overlayLoader").show(),window.location.href="matches.html",cognitosync("Web","LastLoginOS"))}}function isPhoneKey(e,t){var n=e.which?e.which:event.keyCode;return!(n>31&&(n<48||n>57))&&!($(t).val().length>9)}function isOTPKey(e,t){var n=e.which?e.which:event.keyCode;return!(n>31&&(n<48||n>57))&&!($(t).val().length>0)}function delayedredirect(){window.location.href="matches.html"}function cognitosync(e,t){var n=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID",cognito),o=localStorage.getItem("Email",o),a=localStorage.getItem("Id",a),c=localStorage.getItem("Name",c);client=new AWS.CognitoSyncManager,client.openOrCreateDataset("CrickingDuelsUserInfo",function(c,l){SyncData(l),"stateselect"==t?(l.get("SelectedState",function(e,t){}),l.put("SelectedState",e,function(e,t){}),l.get("DeviceId",function(e,t){}),l.put("DeviceId",n,function(e,t){}),l.get("Email",function(e,t){}),l.put("Email",o,function(e,t){}),l.get("PrimaryEmail",function(e,t){}),l.put("PrimaryEmail",o,function(e,t){}),l.get("UserId",function(e,t){}),l.put("UserId",a,function(e,t){}),l.get("IsFavorites",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsFavorites","true",function(e,t){}),l.get("IsLikeFB",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsLikeFB","false",function(e,t){}),l.get("IsLikeTWITTER",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsLikeTWITTER","false",function(e,t){}),l.get("IsMusicOn",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsMusicOn","false",function(e,t){}),l.get("IsPushOn",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsPushOn","false",function(e,t){}),l.get("IsShowRatecard",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsShowRatecard","false",function(e,t){}),l.get("IsShowSocialMedia",function(e,t){}),l.put("IsShowSocialMedia","false",function(e,t){}),l.get("TriviaQuestions",function(e,t){}),l.put("TriviaQuestions","0",function(e,t){}),l.get("Country",function(e,t){}),l.put("Country","India",function(e,t){}),SyncData(l)):"LastLoginOS"==t?(l.get("LastLoginOS",function(e,t){}),l.put("LastLoginOS","Web",function(e,t){}),SyncData(l)):"PhoneNo"==t?(l.get("PhoneNo",function(e,t){}),l.put("PhoneNo",e,function(e,t){}),SyncData(l)):"GotPhoneNo"==t?(l.get("GotPhoneNo",function(e,t){}),l.put("GotPhoneNo","true",function(e,t){}),SyncData(l)):"referaltaken"==t&&(l.get("ReferralTaken",function(e,t){}),l.put("ReferralTaken",e,function(e,t){}),SyncData(l),setTimeout(delayedredirect,2e3))})}window.fbAsyncInit=function(){FB.init({appId:"1437031366566616",xfbml:!0,version:"v2.10"})},function(e,t,n){var o,a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];e.getElementById(n)||((o=e.createElement(t)).id=n,o.
src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js",a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a))}(document,"script","facebook-jssdk"),document.getElementById("phonenumber_button").addEventListener("click",function(){var e=$("input[name='phone']").val();localStorage.setItem("phone_number",e);var t=Math.floor(1e3+9e3*Math.random());localStorage.setItem("otp",t);var n=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID");$.
ajax({url:'https://ws.cricking.com/ws5/otpsms.php?value={"userid":"'+n+'", "otp":"'+t+'", "tonumber":"'+e+'", "platform":1}',type:"GET",success:function(e){0==(e=JSON.parse(e)).StatusCode&&(document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepOne").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepTwo").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepThree").style.display="block")}}),cognitosync(e,"PhoneNo")}),document.getElementById("resend_code").addEventListener("click",function(){var e=localStorage.getItem("phone_number"),t=localStorage.getItem("otp"),n=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID");$.
ajax({url:'https://ws.cricking.com/ws5/otpsms.php?value={"userid":"'+n+'", "otp":"'+t+'", "tonumber":"'+e+'", "platform":1}',type:"GET",success:function(e){0==(e=JSON.parse(e)).StatusCode&&(document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepTwo").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepThree").style.display="block")}})}),document.getElementById("otp_submit").addEventListener("click",function(){var e=$("input[name='otp1']").val()+$("input[name='otp2']").val()+$("input[name='otp3']").val()+$("input[name='otp4']").val(),t=localStorage.getItem("otp"),n=localStorage.getItem("phone_number"),o=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID");t==e&&($.ajax({url:'https://ws.cricking.com/ws5/userregistration.php?value={"tonumber":"'+n+'","userid":"'+o+'"}',type:"GET",success:function(e){}}),cognitosync("true","GotPhoneNo"),document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepTwo").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepThree").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepOne").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountReferralCode").style.display="block")}),document.getElementById("loginBtn").addEventListener("click",function(){$("#overlayLoader").show(),FB.login(function(e){if(FB.api("/me",{fields:"email,name"},function(e){localStorage.setItem("Email",e.email),localStorage.setItem("Name",e.name),localStorage.setItem("Id",e.id);localStorage.getItem("Email"),localStorage.getItem("Name"),localStorage.getItem("Id"),localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID")}),e.authResponse){setTimeout(myFunction,5e3);var t=e.authResponse.accessToken;if(localStorage.setItem("accesstoken",t),null!=t){var n={IdentityPoolId:"us-east-1:8017b399-3a23-45d6-8407-7271cef062ef",Logins:{"graph.facebook.com":t}};AWS.config.region="us-east-1",AWS.config.credentials=new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(n),AWS.config.credentials.get(function(e,t){AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){AWS.config.credentials.identityId;client=new AWS.CognitoSyncManager,client.openOrCreateDataset("CrickingDuelsUserInfo",function(e,t){SyncData(t),t.getAllRecords(function(e,t){var n=t.length;0==t.length&&client.openOrCreateDataset("CrickingDuelsUserInfo",function(e,t){SyncData(t),t.getAllRecords(function(e,t){})});var o=localStorage.getItem("_internal._metadata"),a=JSON.stringify(o);JSON.parse(a);if(t.length>1){for(var c=0;c<n;c++)if("ReferralTaken"==t[c].key){referralValue={userval:t[c].value};break}localStorage.setItem("userVal",referralValue.userval)}})}),cognito=AWS.config.credentials.identityId,localStorage.setItem("Cognito_ID",cognito)})})}}})}),$("#select_state").click(function(){var e=document.getElementById("user_state");e=$("#user_state option:selected").val();if(""==(selectedValue=e))return M.toast({html:"Select a state"}),!1;"Assam"==selectedValue?(cognitosync("true","referaltaken"),cognitosync(selectedValue,"stateselect"),document.getElementById("accountReferralCode").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepOne").style.display="none"):(cognitosync(selectedValue,"stateselect"),document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepTwo").style.display="block",document.getElementById("accountReferralCode").style.display="none",document.getElementById("accountVerficationStepOne").style.display="none")}),$("#final_refer").click(function(){var e=document.getElementById("refer_code").value,t=localStorage.getItem("Cognito_ID"),n=localStorage.getItem("Email"),o=localStorage.getItem("Name");$.getJSON('https://ws.cricking.com/ws4/?action=playerreferal&value={"UserId":"'+t+'","EmailId":"'+n+'","Code":"'+e+'","UserName":"'+o+'"}').success(function(e){if("0"==e.StatusCode)M.toast({html:"Congrats! Your referral code is valid. Take control! Join Hybrid Fantasy and enjoy Cricking Duels."}),cognitosync("true","referaltaken"),cognitosync("Web","LastLoginOS"),$("#overlayLoader").show();else{if("1"==e.StatusCode)return M.toast({html:"Oops! You entered an invalid referral code. Please check and re-enter the valid referral code."}),!1;if("2"==e.StatusCode)return M.toast({html:"Oops! You entered an invalid referral code. Please check and re-enter the valid referral code."}),!1}})}),$("#skip_refer_code").click(function(){cognitosync("true","referaltaken"),
cognitosync("Web","LastLoginOS"),$("#overlayLoader").show()});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CrickingDuels</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.4.14.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js\cognito\dist\amazon-cognito.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css\materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css\fontawesome\css\font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css\common.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css\login.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://use.typekit.net/wmk2lex.js"></script>
        <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-54357006-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-54357006-1');
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="white">    
    <main>
        <div class="row main-background">
            <div class="">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12 relative" style="padding: 50px 10%;">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row no-margin">
                            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                                <h3 class="blue-text text-darken-4 margin-5-0 bold">Let's</h3>
                                <h3 class="blue-text text-darken-4 margin-5-0 bold">Play</h3>
                                <h3 class="blue-text text-darken-4 margin-5-0 bold">Fantasy!</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row margin-10-0" style="margin-bottom: 30% !important;">
                            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                                <p class="font-16 blue-text text-darken-4 margin-5-0 bold">Play fantasy</p>
                                <p class="font-16 blue-text text-darken-4 margin-5-0 bold">&amp; win cash daily!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row no-margin" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;padding: 0 20px;">
                            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                                <div class="row add-amount no-margin">
                                    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 no-padding push-l3 push-m3 center-align">
                                        <button id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-flat blue darken-3 white-text width-100" style="text-transform: none;"><i class="fa fa-facebook white-text font-14"></i> Sign in with Facebook</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 0;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <div class="modal" id="verification">
        <div class="modal-content blue">

            <div class="row no-margin" id="accountVerficationStepOne">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12 no-padding center-align">
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="images\state_selection.png" class="img responsive-img img-center" width="150">
                    </div>
                    <!-- <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4 bold">State Selection</p> -->
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4">Residents of the states of Assam and Odisha, and where otherwise prohibited by law are not eligible to enter pay leagues, you can play free Leagues</p>
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                        <select class="" name="state" id="user_state">
                            <option value="">--Select a state--</option>
                            <option value="Andaman and Nicobar">Andaman and Nicobar</option>
                            <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
                            <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
                            <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                            <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
                            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                            <option value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                            <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
                            <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                            <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                            <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
                            <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="Jammu and Kashmir">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                            <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
                            <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
                            <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
                            <option value="Lakshadweep">Lakshadweep</option>
                            <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
                            <option value="Manipur">Manipur</option>
                            <option value="Meghalaya">Meghalaya</option>
                            <option value="Mizoram">Mizoram</option>
                            <option value="Nagaland">Nagaland</option>
                            <option value="Odisha">Odisha</option>
                            <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
                            <option value="Puducherry">Puducherry</option>
                            <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
                            <option value="Sikkim">Sikkim</option>
                            <option value="Tamil Nadu">Tamil Nadu</option>
                            <option value="Telangana">Telangana</option>
                            <option value="Tripura">Tripura</option>
                            <option value="Uttarakhand">Uttarakhand</option>
                            <option value="Uttar pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="West bengal">West bengal</option>
                        </select>
                        <button class="btn btn-flat gradient-background white-text margin-10-0" id="select_state">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row no-margin" id="accountVerficationStepTwo" style="display: none;">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12 no-padding center-align">
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="images\mobile_number.png" class="img responsive-img img-center" width="150">
                    </div>
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4 bold">Mobile Verification</p>
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4">Please enter your mobile number</p>
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="browser-default" onkeypress="return isPhoneKey(event, this)" placeholder="+91">
                        <button class="btn btn-flat gradient-background white-text margin-10-0" id="phonenumber_button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row no-margin" id="accountVerficationStepThree" style="display: none;">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12 no-padding">
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="images\sms_otp.png" class="img responsive-img img-center" width="150">
                    </div>
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4 bold center-align">Mobile Verification</p>
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4 center-align">Please enter the OTP you have received on your registered mobile number</p>
                    <div class="form-group center-align" style="padding-top: 30px;margin: 0 auto;">
                        <input type="text" name="otp1" id="otp1" class="browser-default inline center-align" style="width: 16%; padding: 0 5px;" onkeypress="return isOTPKey(event,this)">
                        <input type="text" name="otp2" id="otp2" class="browser-default inline center-align" style="width: 16%; padding: 0 5px;" onkeypress="return isOTPKey(event,this)">
                        <input type="text" name="otp3" id="otp3" class="browser-default inline center-align" style="width: 16%; padding: 0 5px;" onkeypress="return isOTPKey(event,this)">
                        <input type="text" name="otp4" id="otp4" class="browser-default inline center-align" style="width: 16%; padding: 0 5px;" onkeypress="return isOTPKey(event,this)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group center-align resend_code">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="resend_code" class="white-text">Resend code</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group center-align">
                        <button class="btn btn-flat gradient-background white-text margin-10-0" id="otp_submit">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row no-margin" id="accountReferralCode" style="display: none;">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12 no-padding">
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="images\sms_otp.png" class="img responsive-img img-center" width="150">
                    </div>
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4 bold center-align">Referral code</p>
                    <p class="uppercase blue-text text-darken-4 center-align">We want to give you a head start. If you have a referral code, enter it below and we will load &#8377; 89 in your wallet to join the leagues.</p>
                    <div class="form-group center-align" style="padding-top: 30px;margin: 0 auto;">
                        <input type="text" name="refer_code" id="refer_code">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group center-align resend_code">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="skip_refer_code" class="white-text">Skip</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group center-align">
                        <button class="btn btn-flat gradient-background white-text margin-10-0" id="final_refer">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="overlayLoader" style="display: none;">
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="progress thin-4">
                <div class="indeterminate"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-rsPUGdUPBXgalvIj4YKJrrUlmLXbOb6Cp7cdxn1qeUc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="js/dust-full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dust-helpers.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js\cognitosync.js"></script>
    <script src="js\login.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script> -->
</html>
```